# Managing the Azure Windows through PHP SDk

Tags: php, azure

I am trying to configure the php sdk for managing the azure instance to perform basic operations like starting or stopping a VM,getting the IP of running VM,etc.I tried searching but didnt find any document.Is there any document available ? Also how to establish client session for the same ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no SDK for PHP we can use to manage Azure VM at the present time. The REST Management API is the one you want to go for.

Reference:

[Virtual Machines REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines)